# Azure functions - deploy by project in single repo?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions

We are building a set of serverless functions in Azure, but having difficulty deciding how to structure our source (Azure GIT) and DevOps to support them.

I am thinking of a single GIT repo, with all function apps housed independently within projects. We may have a lot of these function apps, we see great value in small code segments to do utility type of work, and I don't want dozens and dozens of independent repos just because of DevOps deployments. Is there a way to have a unique build and release process for each project, not the repo entirely?  We aren't clear how this can be done and searches have come up empty on this. I thought it was possible to have unique build YAMLs per project across many projects in a single repo - but unclear how to implement the DevOps build and release pipleines to support this approach - ie; only a single function gets updated and we need to deploy - any guidance if this is possible and how to approach it would be great.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I think the answer is not to handle this. All of the yml files will be triggered on deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't done this myself, but I'm in a similar situation where I'd like to have multiple functions (and other stuff) in a single Git repo for simplicity, but only build/deploy them as needed when they change. It looks like you can have multiple pipelines on a single repo with a different YAML file for each pipeline. The steps are documented in [this link](https://sethreid.co.nz/using-multiple-yaml-build-definitions-azure-devops/), and summarized below

1. In Azure DevOps, create a new Pipeline.
2. For the "Where is your code?" page, at the bottom choose the **Use the classic editor** option.
3. Select your source repo and branch.
4. On the "Select a template" screen, choose the **YAML** option at the top. Hit Apply.
5. There is a **YAML file path** field where you can specify the path and name of your YAML file for the pipeline.

You may want to set the pipeline to run manually if you don't want a build each time there's a commit to the repo.

**EDIT** There may be an easier way to do this now. If you go through the New Pipeline wizard, select your source location, on the Configure tab, at the bottom you can choose the **Existing Azure Pipelines YAML file** option. This lets you select a custom YAML file directly.

Comment: Thx - I'm a tad unclear though how you direct it to specific projects - and when we do a build, we only want that one function to kick off the build process, not the entire inclusion of projects in the repo.  I'm building these in VS Code with Python and can create function projects - a little different for me than in the past with C# projects in Visual Studio. It looks like it just creates a folder which is nice and seems simple and GIT is happy. So I'm guessing you just set the subfolder in the .YAML file path' but I'm unclear.

Comment: Depending on what else is in your repo, I would have a top level folder for each Function App you want to deploy. (If there's other stuff in there too, maybe a top level folder for Functions, then each app in a directory below it.) I don't know if it matters where the YAML file goes -- either in the root, or in the function directory. Name it something unique for each function, set it to build (and/or release) that function, and in your build pipeline, enter the path of the file. You could also put the release part in a Release pipeline using a build artifact.